# Python - using variable in regex

Tags: python, regex

When I run the below piece of code, Im not getting the expected output.
Please correct me..

```
import socket
import re
NodeName=socket.gethostname()
change_hostname_list=['/etc/hosts1','/etc/sysconfig/network1']
for file in change_hostname_list:
        infile=open(file,'r').read()
        print NodeName
        print file
        if re.search('NodeName',file):
                print "DOOO"
```

I need the output "DOOO"

I'm getting the below one,

```
root@test06> python test.py
test06
/etc/hosts1
test06
/etc/sysconfig/network1
root@test06>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not searching the wrong thing? Maybe try `re.search(file, NodeName)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
if re.search('NodeName',file):
```

to :

```
if re.search(NodeName,infile):
```

you don't need quote for variable, file variable is the filename from list, variable file has the content of the file.

here is the demo:

```
>>> import socket
>>> import re
>>> f = open('/etc/hosts')
>>> host_name =  socket.gethostname()
>>> host_name
'hackaholic'
>>> for x in f:
...     print(x)
...     if re.search(host_name,x):
...         print("found")
... 
127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.0.1   hackaholic

found     # it founds the host name in file
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: NodeName can contain special regular expression characters. Check out my answer - you may be good to go with `string.find`.

Comment: It worked, after changing it to infile and tried the old substring find() also.. Both worked:)

Comment: yep you are giving wrong variable name that why its was not working

Answer (score 1):

Drop the quotes if NodeName is string it should just do string search in file.

```
import socket
import re
NodeName=socket.gethostname()
change_hostname_list=['/etc/hosts1','/etc/sysconfig/network1']
for file in change_hostname_list:
    infile=open(file,'r').read()
    print NodeName
    print file
    if re.search(NodeName,file):
        print "DOOO"
```

If you need to use some regex goodies you can concat the variable to create regular expression string and pass it to `re.search`.

Also, if you don't need any regular expression stuff, just plain old substring search, you can use string function `find` used as follows:

```
if file.find(NodeName):
    print "DOOO"
```

Comment: this is not going to work, its infile not file, is not about search and fine its about the variable name

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be passing the string `'NodeName'` to `re.search()` as a pattern instead of the variable `NodeName`. Remove the single quotes in line 9 of the code you provided.